# make user upload image to in theme folder

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, themes

i am developing a wordpress theme. i want to make my users' images saved in NOT https://example.com/wp-content/uploads folder, but in https://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images folder.

i added this code to my themes' functions.php file :

```
    function my_custom_upload_dir( $dir ) {
    return array(
        'path'   => WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/portfolio/images',
        'url'    => WP_CONTENT_URL . '/portfolio/images',
        'subdir' => '/portfolio/images',
    ) + $dir;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'my_custom_upload_dir' );
```

and i got this error :

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/portfolio/images. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

i dont want to save in wp-content/uploads/portfolio/images file, i want to save in wp-contect/themes/mytheme/images file. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: something like `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() '/portfolio/images'`

Comment: "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/portfolio/images. Is its parent directory writable by the server?" same error. i dont want to save to wp-content/upload directory. i need to upload to DİRECTLY in theme folder